# how to resolve Error: $ is not defined in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net mvc in that i am using partial views but i get the following error

Error: $ is not defined
Line: 159

it is for the java script its not getting reference. i included the java script in site.master

```
     <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../Scripts/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../Scripts/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

first js is for partial view. and my function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dt = { changeYear: true, yearRange: "-6:+6" }
        $("#FromDate").datepicker(dt);
    });
</script>
```

so can you tell me how to resolve reference problem.because of that date picker is also not working and partial views also not working but on local host it works fine but on server nothing is working.
i also used  src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/XXXX.js")%>" but still its not working on server.
thank you.

Comment: Why are you loading 2 different versions of jQuery?

Comment: why you're including 2 jquery libraries? Do you get any javascript error on the page?

Comment: Why are you installing **two** versions of jQuery? (And two **old** versions, at that?) That's definitely not going to work out for you. (*edit*  great minds think alike!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem will be with the path to the scripts I think. 
Where you have

```
src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"
```

you probably need to change this to something like

```
src="/Something/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"
```

you could also try referencing an external version (as SO does).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's one of two things:

1. You're including jquery-1.2.6.js and jquery-1.3.2.js.  One is messing with the other.
2. The files are not being loaded at all.  Can you use firebug and look at the net tab to see that they are successfully be loaded?

Comment: its working on localhost properly it gives problem when i deploy it on server. plz tell me solution if you konw all js files are properly loaded thanks

Comment: So the js files do *not* get loaded correctly when you deploy it to the server?  Try using absolute paths as mdresser mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

can you check what happens when you replace $ with jQuery? does it works. Also try doing `alert(jQuery)` if it is undefined that means your libraries are not loaded and you need to check for your paths.Also as mentioned try using one latest version of jQuery than two.

Answer (score 0):

In your View or PartialView, try wrapping your javascript in @section scripts, this will allow it to reference the scripts you have in Layout, if you have the commonly used  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) in your _Layout.cshtml.

```
@section scripts
{
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var dt = { changeYear: true, yearRange: "-6:+6" }
        $("#FromDate").datepicker(dt);
      });
}
```